# is there universal/default IP for accessing routers web interface

Tags: macos, router, netstat, ifconfig, ipconfig

I have a requirement where i need to access routers web interface and extract few information.

**I'm assuming that 192.168.1.1 will be default router IP address for every different types of router ( even different manufacturers ) to access the web interface.**
1. I'm correct on this assumption ?

**Also since i read couple of articles like mentioned below and it looks like the default IP address to access web interface of router will change according to manufacturers. Is this correct as per below articles ?**

1.http://forums.xfinity.com/t5/Home-Networking-Router-WiFi/Re-how-find-out-the-IP-address-of-my-comcast-modem-router/m-p/2288073#U2288073

2.http://customer.xfinity.com/help-and-support/internet/comcast-supported-routers-gateways-adapters/

3.http://www.answersthatwork.com/Download_Area/ATW_Library/Networking/Network__4-List_of_default_Router_Admin_Passwords_and_IP_addresses.pdf

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

> I'm assuming that 192.168.1.1 will be default router IP address for every different types of router [..]. I'm correct on this assumption ?

**No.** It depends on the network configuration what the router's IP is. `192.168.1.1` is a *pretty popular* default IP address, but it is by no means the only possible address or even the most often used address.* Any router could have any possible address it wanted.

<sub>* (70% of all statistics are made up on the spot)</sub>

> the default IP address to access web interface of router will change according to manufacturers

**Yes.** The particular URL, IP or DNS name is entirely dependent on the particular router's model, make and configuration. There is no universal constant.